# Как добавить условие к регулярному выражению?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такая регулярка `^[А-ЯЁ]?[а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)?$`

Пропускает:

- Анна
- анна
- Анна-Мария

Фильтрует неверные варианты:

- анна-
- Анна-

Не получается разрешить пропуск следующих вариантов:

- анна-мария
- Анна-мария
- анна-Мария

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По описанию вроде так:

```
^[А-ЯЁа-яё]+(?:-[А-ЯЁа-яё]+)?$
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. По каким источникам изучали регулярки и как получается их постоянно помнить?

Comment: @Novikov, берёшь [вот это](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf) и [страницу википедии с описанием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и с учётом поддержки только PCRE-части (впрочем, в js уже добавили lookbehind, когда я делал, им и не пахло) решаешь все задания. За день всё выучишь.

Answer (score 0):

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"[А-я]+`\`-[А-я]+|[А-я]+")

Так будет попроще, применимо к гугл-таблицам.
Сначала выражение должно искать совпадение по "Имя"-"Имя", т.к если находится более короткое подходящее регулярное выражение, то поиск сразу заканчивается.
Но если поиск не находит вариант с длинным регулярным выражением, тогда срабатывает условие | или:
и поиск ищет только короткое регулярное выражение "Имя".